# Praw not responding

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit, praw, bitcoind

I dont really know why my code doesn't work. When my Reddit bot gets a message or comment with "+makeaccount" it should "contact" bitcoind and make an account with "getnewaddress" and print a message to the console, but it doesn't seem to even print to the console. This is my code:

```
import praw
from contextlib import suppress
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy, JSONRPCException

# Authenticate with Reddit
reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id='',
    client_secret='',
    user_agent='',
    username='',
    password=''
)

reddit.validate_on_submit = True

# Print the username of the bot
print(reddit.user.me())

# TODO: Collect this data
#def getinboxdata(inboxdata):
# for item in reddit.inbox.all(limit=None):
#    print(repr(item))


# Define the bot's response to a comment
def get_balance():
    rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:22225" % ('user', 'pass'))
    get_balance = rpc_connection.getbalance()
    return get_balance # This will print the balance

def withdraw(address, amount):
    rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:22225" % ('user', 'pass'))
    withdraw = rpc_connection.sendtoaddress(address, amount)
    return withdraw

def getnewaddress(user):
    rpc_connection = AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:22225" % ('user', 'pass'))
    getnewaddress = rpc_connection.getnewaddress(user)
    return getnewaddress

# Commands
with suppress(Exception):
 while True:
  for item in reddit.inbox.unread(limit=None):
     if item.body.startswith("+withdraw"):
          print(item.author.name + " requested a withdraw")
          command=item.body
          command_splitted = command.split(" ")
          address = command_splitted[1]
          amount = command_splitted[2]
          print(address, amount)
          item.mark_read()
          withdraw(address, amount)
          item.reply("Withdrawal of " + amount + " BKC to " + address + " successful.")
          print("Withdrew " + amount + " to " + address)
          item.mark_read()

while True:
  for item in reddit.inbox.unread(limit=None):
     if item.body.startswith("+makeaccount"):
            print("bruh")
            print(item.author.name + " requested a new account")
            user = item.author.name
            withdraw(user)
            item.reply("It's dangerous to go alone, take this!")
            print("Created account for " + user)
            item.mark_read()
```

Comment: you can't run two `while True` loops at the same time - first loop runs forever and other loop never starts. You can run every loop in separated thread/processes - or simply put all `if item.body.startswith(...):...` in one `while True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run two `while True` loops at the same time.

First loop runs forever and other loop never starts.

You can run every loop in separated thread/processes

but simpler is to put all `if item.body.startswith(...):...` in one `while True`

```
with suppress(Exception):
 while True:
  for item in reddit.inbox.unread(limit=None):

     if item.body.startswith("+withdraw"):
          print(item.author.name + " requested a withdraw")
          command=item.body
          command_splitted = command.split(" ")
          address = command_splitted[1]
          amount = command_splitted[2]
          print(address, amount)
          item.mark_read()
          withdraw(address, amount)
          item.reply("Withdrawal of " + amount + " BKC to " + address + " successful.")
          print("Withdrew " + amount + " to " + address)
          item.mark_read()

     if item.body.startswith("+makeaccount"):
            print("bruh")
            print(item.author.name + " requested a new account")
            user = item.author.name
            withdraw(user)
            item.reply("It's dangerous to go alone, take this!")
            print("Created account for " + user)
            item.mark_read()
```